# Prevent Lenovo Phab2 from automatically activating mobile data when WiFi is switched off

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, settings, mobile-data, lenovo

My device is Lenovo Phab 2 running Android 6.0. I enabled the "turning on mobile data when WiFi is turned off" feature and cannot disable it again from Device settings after a lot of searches.

The only solution I have now is to restore my device to the factory, but this is my last choice.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → Apps settings → Storage → Clear Data. This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

It's in developer options section.

[image: DevOps]
<sub>Click to enlarge image</sub>

Comment: Which option is it then? I can only see an option to ***always*** have mobile data on. OP asked for "turning on user data when wifi is turned off". Or did I miss something?